# Get the longest route from collection of polygons

Tags: python, javascript

```
const startPoint = [x,y];
const nodes = [[x,y], [x,y]....];

const polygons = [...];

const createConnectedPath = (startPoint, nodes, polygons) => {
 // The path should follow the center of each polygon. 
 // The path should connect the startpoint with the node which have the longest path when following the path through the polygons.
 // The polygon is not required to be "connected" with another polygon. If so, connect the closest polygon with one another.
};

expectedOutput = [startpoint, [x,y][x,y][x,y]]; // A path
```

Is there any package that have this functionality out of the box? If not, what would be the correct way to approach this?

I'm thinking the first step would be to convert the polygon to lines. Then extend all lines until they intersect with another line. Then somehow connect each node with the closest line from the polygon. From there calculate the **longest** route and create a path of this route. Am I close? Or totally off?

It's a local coordinate system. Not GIS coordinates.

Totally new to this kind of logic; can anyone just point me in the right direction?

Python or JavaScript are preferred languages.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rough, but something like this will work for connecting the polygons in a path. Note that I've change your rectangles to squares for the sake of simplicity, but it should still work. If you need it to work with irregular shaped polygons, you'll probably need to find the centroid.

```
let currentPoint = [0, 0];

const nodes = [
  [-3, 0],
  [-3, 3],
  [-5, 2],
  [-6, 0],
  [-6, -3]
];

// [LL, UL, UR, LR]
const polygons = [
  [[-1, 1], [-1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 1]],
  [[-4, 1], [-4, 3], [-2, 3], [-2, 1]],
  [[-7, 0], [-7, 2], [-5, 2], [-5, 0]]
];

// Polygons that are on a collision course with our current point
// [Index in polygon array, Distance to polygon]
const found = [];

const path = [];

const extendLine = (direction, max) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    currentPoint = [currentPoint[0] + direction[0], currentPoint[1] + direction[1]];

    console.log('currentPoint: ', currentPoint);

    const index = checkForCollision(currentPoint);
    if (index !== null) {
      found.push([index, i]); // Push index of found polygon, and i as measurement of distance to polygon
      console.log('Pushed: ', [index, i]);
      break;
    }
  }
};

// Check if point falls between a polygon's LL and UR
const checkForCollision = (point) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
    const polygon = polygons[i];
    if (
      point[0] > polygon[0][0]
      && point[0] < polygon[2][0]
      && point[1] > polygon[0][1]
      && point[1] < polygon[2][1]
    ) {
      console.log(`Found collision at: ${i}`);
      return i; // Return the index of the found polygon
    }
  }

  return null;
};

// Might want this to round this down for simplicity
const findCenter = (ll, ur) => {
  return [((ll[0] + ur[0]) / 2), ((ll[1] + ur[1]) / 2)];
};

const createConnectedPath = () => {
  console.log('Creating connected path...');

  path.push(currentPoint);

  // Look for polygons first
  while (polygons.length > 0) {
    extendLine([0, 1], 10); // Extend North
    extendLine([1, 0], 10); // Extend East
    extendLine([0, -1], 10); // Extend South
    extendLine([-1, 0], 10); // Extend West

    let closest = null;
    for (let i = 0; i < found.length; i++) {
      const polygon = found[i];
      if (closest === null || polygon[1] < closest[1]) {
        closest = polygon;
      }
    }

    if (!closest) {
      throw new Error('No polygons found within search distance');
    }

    // Set our new current point to the center of the closest polygon
    currentPoint = findCenter(polygons[closest[0]][0], polygons[closest[0]][2]);

    // Add this to our path
    path.push(currentPoint);

    // Remove the polygon so we won't have to search through it again
    polygons.splice(closest[0], 1);
  }

  // TODO: Done -> find closest node

  console.log('Path:');
  console.log(path);
};

createConnectedPath();
```

Once all of the polygons are found, you'd just need to finish this up by finding the closest node.

Comment: I just realized that this isn't going to meet your "connect the closest polygon with one another" requirement; you'd have to recalculate the distance from every last connected node. If you don't have a lot of nodes and performance isn't an issue, you can simply do the recalculation. If performance is an issue, you're going to want to look into path finding algorithms, such as Dijkstra's: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: I think you misunderstod. The nodes should not be connected. Only one node should be connected and create the path via the polygons to the start point. The node to be connected is the one which have the longest distance (longest via the polygons, not a straight line).

Comment: I've added a picture.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, polygons are going to need to share the same X or Y plane as another polygon, so no diagonal movement? You'll essentially want to do a raycast: extending a line in each of the cardinal directions from your starting point. At certain intervals you'll want to check if there has been a collision with one of your polygons (which you can calculate since you know their boundaries). If there are multiple collisions, you can check which polygon is the closest to determine which to connect with first. You would then repeat this process from the center of that polygon.

Comment: Yes. So do I need to write all this logic myself or is there any neat package that do this for me? At least some of it?

Comment: I don't think this is really a GIS question as much as it is a path finding problem. For existing packages, game engines actually have a lot of tools to address things like this, but I think it should be easy enough to solve yourself. I'll write up a quick example solution and change my answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a sample script.